# Unpack the pak file - Unreal Engine

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

So I have the encryption key. This is stressed so much to have it. Well, I have it. Where do I use it? Unrealpak does not seems to offer an option to supply the encryption key, if your pak is encypted - the unpackaging simply fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that keys can be supplied with a json

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included the steps for how to provide the keys via json